# Numpy how to get selective arrays in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Here is sample:

```
t = np.random.randint(10, 20, size=(2, 3, 5))

array([[[11, 16, 13, 18, 19],
        [13, 18, 14, 19, 15],
        [12, 16, 12, 15, 12]],

       [[18, 16, 12, 11, 19],
        [14, 18, 13, 16, 17],
        [18, 17, 16, 16, 10]]])
```

I would like to select the arrays of [0, 1, :] and [1, 2, :],

that shapes as below: (2, 5)

```
[[13, 18, 14, 19, 15],
[18, 17, 16, 16, 10]]
```

I tried the code below but it won't give me the correct answer

```
t[:, [1, 2], :]
array([[[13, 18, 14, 19, 15],
        [12, 16, 12, 15, 12]],

       [[14, 18, 13, 16, 17],
        [18, 17, 16, 16, 10]]])
```

I can iterate to get the arrays and concat them to make the shape I wanted, but I wonder if there is any way to get the correct arrays using indices.

Thank you.

Comment: `idx0 = [0,1]; idx1 = [1,2] ; out = t[idx0,idx1]`?

Comment: that gives me the same wrong answer like above

Comment: You are looking to get `[[13, 18, 14, 19, 15], [18, 17, 16, 16, 10]]`, right?

Comment: yes! what you are asking is right

Comment: So, have you actually tried what I suggested?

Comment: yes that gives same answer as t[:, [1, 2], :]

Comment: woop sorry i made a mistake your answer works!

Comment: Please add a python tag

Comment: @Divakar Can you also help me one more problem? How do I get t[[0, 1, 2], [0:2, 2:4, 1:3], :] like this? I want the middle part somewhat sequential but the starting and end positions of the middle part is different at axis=0. How can I find it?

Comment: @IsaacSim Please post a new question.